# MySQL caindo por falta de memória

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Tenho um servidor dedicado **Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** com **MySQL/Apache/Wordpress**, só que como ele tem apenas 1Gb de RAM, as vezes ele cai por falta de memória.
No syslog marca com a mensagem

> Out of memory: Kill process XXXXX (mysqld) score XXXXXX or sacrifice child

e depois

> mysql respawning too fast, stopped

Há alguma solução para que o daemon do MySQL continue tentando voltar, mas com intervalos maiores (como 5 minutos)?

** Atualização:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf: http://pastebin.com/Vy19ZZTR

Comment: Você pode colar que valor está para `innodb_buffer_pool_size` no seu arquivo`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`?

Comment: Aliás seria legal colar um link para suas configurações do `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. É possível que o motivo para o mysql não conseguir reiniciar esteja nesse arquivo.

Comment: Atualizei com a configuração do MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Checar quantidade máxima de memória que seu servidor teoricamente poderia usar

Use o script `MySQLTuner`, disponível em https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl, e siga as recomendações dele. Ele de início já vai dizer quanta memória seu banco de dados poderia usar em um momento de estresse. Certifique-se que ela seja menor do que você realmente tem, ou pelo menos cheque se tem swap habilitada.

### SWAP

Além de configurar seu MySQL para usar menos memória, algo que deve ser feito sempre em máquinas virtuais pequenas é criar SWAP. Um banco de dados funcionar em SWAP não é uma boa idéia, mas pelo menos sua aplicação não vai parar por falta de memória.

Em https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04 explica como fazer esse processo com CentOS.

Execute o comando

`sudo swapon -s`

e veja se retorna um valor com tamanho da SWAP. Se não retornar, ela deve ser criada.

Comment: Ótima dica, estou testando para ver se resolve.

Comment: Funcionou o Swap, o servidor nunca mais caiu, obrigado!